# How can I get answer right under each question I made with two option buttons of right and wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I made a html file with javascript. It is questions with two buttons (True & not true). When I press each one it shows up either Right or Wrong

For example:
Earth is the biggest planet? True  - Not true

My question is simple but Im new so idk how. How can I align the answer under each questions. Because when I made the code, the answer for each questions shows up at the bottom

```js
window.onload = start;

function start() {}

function showCorrect() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = event.target.value;
}
```

```html
<label>There is 365 days in a year</label>
<button value="Right" onclick="showCorrect(event)">True</button>
<button value="Wrong" onclick="showCorrect(event)">Not true</button>

<br>

<label>December is the first month of a year</label>
<button value="Wrong" onclick="showCorrect(event)">True</button>
<button value="Right" onclick="showCorrect(event)">Not true</button>

<p id="text"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define answer to each question and not one answer to both questions.

```js
window.onload = start;

function start() {}

function showCorrect(e, id) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = event.target.value;
}
```

```html
<label>There is 365 days in a year</label>
<button value="Right" onclick="showCorrect(event, 'text1')">True</button>
<button value="Wrong" onclick="showCorrect(event, 'text1')">Not true</button>
<p id="text1"></p>
<br>

<label>December is the first month of a year</label>
<button value="Wrong" onclick="showCorrect(event, 'text2')">True</button>
<button value="Right" onclick="showCorrect(event, 'text2')">Not true</button>

<p id="text2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Various ways. Here's one.

First, give each question and answer set its own container.

```
<div class=q>
    <label>There is 365 days in a year</label>
    <button value="Right" onclick="showCorrect(event)">True</button>
    <button value="Wrong" onclick="showCorrect(event)">Not true</button>
</div>
```

Then in your JS, we can move the `#text` element around depending on which question was answered. We append it to that question's container.

```
let text = document.querySelector('#text');
function showCorrect(event) {
    text.textContent = event.target.value;
    evt.target.closest('.q').appendChild(text);
}
```

PS don't forget `showCorrect` needs to be defined as expecting an argument, the event object (you omit this in your original code.)